# Apagar arquivo definitivamente do Intellij

Tags: python-3.x, intellij-idea

Criei um arquivo `File` do tipo `Text` quando deveria ser um arquivo `.py`. Depois de tentar renomear o arquivo para `.py` ou excluí-lo a IDE não consegue identificar a extensão, não identando o meu código. Como faço para criar um arquivo com esse mesmo nome mas com a extensão correta?

Obs. Já tentei deletar o arquivo com `Safe delete` (`ALT + del`)

Comment: Se você não estiver conseguindo excluir pela IDE, você pode abrir a pasta no local onde está seu projeto e apaga o arquivo você mesmo, e mais uma coisa o Intellij é uma IDE voltada para o desenvolvimento de Java, existe o Pycharm uma IDE para Python criado pela mesma empresa.

Comment: Apagar o arquivo na pasta não resolveu meu problema. Ao tentar criar o mesmo arquivo a IDE continua não identificando a extensão .py

Comment: Todo o ambiente do IntelliJ foi desenvolvido para Java, ele não possui suporte nativo para Python, quando o IntelliJ detecta uma extensão como .py ele oferece um plugin para você instalar para passar a ter suporte, o que não é aconselhável carregar um ambiente todo para Java se você vai editar arquivos Python, para isso recomendo o Visual Studio Code ótimo editor de texto com suporte para diversas linguagens, e o Pycharm a IDE que a JetBrains criou para Python.

Answer (score -1):

Olá amigo o ideal seria utilizar o PyCharm como disse o colega acima O Intellij deve ser utilizado para o Java. Você utiliza o Python junto com o projeto Anaconda, tem a IDE Spyder vem junto o Jupyter Notebook para ajudar a compilar o código, espero ter ajudado, abraço!